# Android - ResourcesNotFoundException when trying to set Action Bar icon by resource id

Tags: android, resources, android-actionbar

I am changing my Action Bar icon to [CircleImageView](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView) that shows profile picture:

```
CircleImageView actionBarIcon_Profile = new CircleImageView(this);
actionBarIcon_Profile.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_picture));
actionBarIcon_Profile.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(48, 48));
actionBarIcon_Profile.setId(R.id.actionBarIcon_Profile);

getActionBar().setIcon(R.id.actionBarIcon_Profile);
```

The ids are kept in ids.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item type="id" name="actionBarIcon_Profile"/>
</resources>
```

I get ResourcesNotFoundException. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: dont you think you should put image path in seticon setIcon(R.drawable.profilepic);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setIcon` is expecting to receive an id of a resource. That id `actionBarIcon_Profile` is just an unique id you're creating that has no resource associated with it. That's why you're getting `ResourcesNotFoundException`.

You can set a drawable to your actionbar's `setIcon` method. Not an imageview. You need to create a circular drawable instead of a circular imageView.