# How to set View to ActionBar icon? not by drawable

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, imageview

I'm trying to use [CircleImageView](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView) as ActionBar icon (like chatting activity in WhatsApp). I've tried [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26905618/android-resourcesnotfoundexception-when-trying-to-set-action-bar-icon-by-resou):

```
CircleImageView actionBarIcon_Profile = new CircleImageView(this);
actionBarIcon_Profile.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_picture));
actionBarIcon_Profile.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(48, 48));
actionBarIcon_Profile.setId(R.id.actionBarIcon_Profile);

getActionBar().setIcon(R.id.actionBarIcon_Profile);
```

ids.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item type="id" name="actionBarIcon_Profile"/>
</resources>
```

It seems like ActionBar setIcon() only accepts drawables as input. I could have setup [a circular shape xml and put it in my drawable folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105775/imageview-in-circular-through-xml), but even that I have to change the background of that xml file to fit my need. Any suggestions?

Comment: you can create simple png for circle. and set it as drawable programatically

Answer (score 0):

link - http://javatechig.com/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android

see if this link helps you

Comment: I understand that I can do that as well, but that would change the entire action bar. I just want to change the icon. If it isn't possible to do, I would definitely try your solution.